# iPhone flashlight when taking photo

Tags: iphone

I need to take a photo in very dim conditions with my iPhone. I use the flashlight to see in these conditions but when I take a photo the flashlight goes out. Is there a way to have the flashlight stay on when taking a photo with an iPhone 7?

Comment: Is there some reason why turning the flash on in the Camera App does not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The camera app controls the flashlight so turn on flash in the camera app (tap the little lightning symbol --> tap on) if you don’t want the default or current setting turn off the flash and capture a non-lit scene.